# Please help with kodi and disabled monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, kodi

I check  Blank other displays  option on kodi. And when play movie on tv kodi dim my main monitor, but after stop movie and close kodi my main display not turn on. I try restart, uncheck  Blank other displays, but nothing happens. In system-> display and monitors i see display is grayed. On ati control center is same. On ati i try enable display but nothing happens. From dropdown chacnge disabled to multiple or single and apply but not effect. Please help me fix this problem.

DFP 3 is dimmed monitor

Output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 640mm x 360mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9     24.0     50.0     25.0     60.1     24.0     60.0  
   1776x1000      50.0     59.9     24.0     50.0     25.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      50.0     60.0     59.9     24.0     25.0     24.0  
   1400x1050      50.0     60.0     59.9     24.0     25.0     24.0  
   1600x900       50.0     59.9     24.0     25.0  
   1360x1024      50.0     60.0     59.9     24.0     25.0     24.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       50.0     59.9     24.0     25.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x900       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8  
   1280x800       60.0  
   1280x768       60.0  
   1280x720       50.0     60.0     59.9  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1152x648       50.0     59.9  
   800x600        60.3  
   848x480        60.0  
   720x480        60.1     60.0     60.1     59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
DFP3 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1440x900       59.9 +
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       75.0     60.0  
   1280x900       75.0     60.0  
   1360x768       59.9  
   1280x800       75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       59.9     66.8  
   1280x768       75.0     60.0  
   1280x720       75.0     60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   848x480        75.0     70.1     60.0  
   720x480        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     59.9  
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made my self a little script to switch screens (I've two identical LCD in splitscreen vs one Beamer so I changed the script to match your case)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(xrandr | grep "DFP3 connected") ]]; then
    xrandr --output DFP2 --mode 1920x1080 --output DFP3 --off
else
    xrandr --output DFP3 --mode 1440x900 --output DFP2 --off
fi
```

Just save this as `/usr/local/bin/switch-tv` make it executable and run `switch-tv` from Terminal to switch between monitor and TV

Answer (score 0):

i fix my problem with this
xrandr --output DFP3 --mode 1440x900 --rate 59.9
and monitor turn on. After this i see In system-> display and monitors  checkbox for enable monitor, but before i not see his. checkbox is hidden on window. Last version of kodi is very buggy - this problem with  Blank other displays option - not return monitor to on, after close kodi, not render properly any 3d format. I uninstall kodi, and install Bino 3D. For my surprise bino 3d work perfectly on 15.04, on 14.04 bino crash and not play movies. Bino have is simple and fast and have only 1 disadvantage - missing hardware acdeleration, but i play half over under(1920x540) for my passive 3d tv and not problem with pc speed.